# How to enable both passwords at registration AND email confirmation together?

Tags: users, emails

I know how to enable setting the password at registration, and I know also how to set email confirmation after registration. But I don't know how to enable both features to work together.

When I enable the former function, the ladder would stop works.

Is it possible to enable both functions using UI?

I have tried Login Toboggan module but it doesn't have this function, either.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to use is the [user registration password module](https://drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword)

> Let users register with a password on the registration form when
> verification mail is required.
>
> By default, users can create accounts directly on the registration
> form, set their password and be immediately logged in, or they can
> create their account, wait for a verification e-mail, and then create
> their password. With this module, users are able to create their
> account along with their password and simply activate their account
> when receiving the verification email.

Comment: I have tried to set this module. I have checked "Require a verification e-mail, but let users set their password directly on the registration form." checkbox on account settings page. But I still receive email from category "Welcome (no approval required, password is set)" without activation link. I thing it is a bug I will create an issue on module project page.

Comment: @tomas.teicher I'm having the same issue, were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: @CR47 No, I have coded this functionality by myself in my custom module, for my specific need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Email Registration](https://drupal.org/project/email_registration) module to

> Allows users to register with an e-mail address as their username

and [User registration password](https://drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword) to

> Let users register with a password on the registration form when
>   verification mail is required.